# Which publication type for forthcoming papers in BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to cite a forthcoming paper (paper that is accepted, but still not published, I guess?). However when I use the `unpublished` or `proceedings` publication type I don't get the result I want. Some fields in from my `bib` file are always missing in the final `pdf` file.

Result I want to see:

> Author, Name (2011) "Name of the article," Name of the journal, Vol.
>   15, forthcoming.

What kind of publication type for forthcoming papers should I use? There are also some types of publication that I can't find their counterpart in BibDesk, like a chapter in a book written by an author, but the book is edited by another. For example:

> Ritter, Jay R., 2002, Investment banking and securities issuance, in
>   G. Constantinides, M. Harris, and R. Stulz, eds.: Handbook of the
>   Economics of Finance (North-Holland, New York, NY)

Comment: This depends not on BibDesk, but on the bibliography style you are using. Are you using `natbib` or `biblatex`, and which bibliography style? For chapters of books, you use the type `incollection`, which allows for an author and an editor.

Comment: I'm using `natbib` and the bibliography style from here http://shirotakeda.org/home/tex/econ-bst.html (if it's what you mean)

Comment: You can add: "accepted" to the note field under whatever type you currently have. If note is not there by default you can add it from a menu item. Note should show up in the biblio, but as others said that is not entirely up to BibDesk.

Comment: You have very nice answers below, but you run the risk of the field suggested below to not appear in the final document at all. So, it can depend on the bibliography style. A robust option, can be to add the word "(accepted)" to the end of the journal name. That way you make sure that this information it will appear. I used to put this in the year filed `year = {(accepted) 2016}` but it doesn't play well with some reference styles.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For forthcoming articles of the sort that you give in your question, the easiest solution is to simply format them as `article` type, and then put "to appear" in the `pages` field.  A forthcoming article won't have a page range yet, and when the article is published you will have to add the page range anyway. In the `econ` bibliography style, (and in fact most bibliography styles for `article`) the page range appears last in the entry, so it will be formatted as you wish.

Alternatively, (as pointed out in the comments) you can add the "to appear" as a `note` field.  To do this in BibDesk, you need to do the following:

1. Open the entry for the article
2. In the Publication menu, choose Add Field
3. In the pulldown textbox, choose Note

This solution is semantically good, but in practice it may not be as robust as putting the "to appear" in the `pages` field, since the appearance of the field depends on the particular bibliography style you are using; if the style isn't set up to output the `note` field, then the problem will reappear.

(Another common way to do this is to not give a year, and replace the `year` field with "to appear". This will, of course, replace it in both bibliography and citations.)

For chapters in books, the `incollection` entry type should be used. The `inbook` entry (which may have been what you were using) is really designed for referring to a particular chapter of a single-authored or edited book; you're not likely to use it much at all, since most citations of that sort can be done using the `book` entry and adding the chapter reference to the citation command.

Comment: When using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, you'll get `p. to appear` if you put `to appear` in your `pages`, which looks weird to me. For me, putting it into `notes` works better (both for `article` and `inproceedings`).

Answer (score 22):

`BibLaTeX` (not BibTeX) defines a field `pubstate`, where you can set different types like `inpress`, `submitted`, `forthcoming`, etc. From the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| inpreparation | The expression ‘in preparation’ (the manuscript is being prepared for publication). |
| submitted | The expression ‘submitted’ (the manuscript has been submitted to a journal or conference). |
| forthcoming | The expression ‘forthcoming’ (the manuscript has been accepted by a press or journal). |
| inpress | The expression ‘in press’ (the manuscript is fully copyedited and out of the author’s hands; it is in the final stages of the production process). |
| prepublished | The expression ‘pre-published’ (the manuscript is published in a preliminary form or location, such as online version in advance of print publication). |

For example,

```
@inproceedings{
  ...
  pubstate={forthcoming},
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the field "intype":

```
    intype = {to appear in},
```

Note:  this works with (at least) IEEEtranS.bst

Comment: But not with `IEEEtran.bst`…