# Truncation of "year" field in author-year citations using "apalike" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use the `natbib` package (with the default `authoryear` option) and the `apalike` bibliography style for bibliographies.

I would like to cite a forthcoming paper in such a way that "forthcoming" or "to appear" is used in place of a year of publication -- both in inline citations and in the bibliography.

If I use the following bibtex entry...

```
@Unpublished{ key,
   title="Title", 
   author="F. Lastname", 
   year="to appear", 
   note="Manuscript under submision" }
```

...then `\citep{key}` expands to `(Lastname pear)` rather than the desired `(Lastname to appear)`.  Similarly, if I use "forthcoming" in the year field, `\citep{key}` expands to `(Lastname ming)`.  It appears that the year field is being truncated to its last four characters.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I should note that although this sort of citation is common, it's not very good practice: the article you are citing *does* have a year, namely the year of the draft you read, and should be cited with that year, and a note saying that it is to appear.  See [Which publication type for forthcoming papers in BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23023/2693) for some ideas on how best to implement this.

That being said, it's not that difficult to modify the bibliography style to allow this kind of year.

This truncation is a property of how the `apalike.bst` style is set up.  Make a copy of `apalike.bst` and make the following modification to it.  Save it as `myapalike.bst` in your local `texmf` folder.  It should go in `<path/to/local>/texmf/bibtex/bst` (where the path is dependent on your OS).  Then use `\bibliographystyle{myapaplike}` in your document.

Find the FUNCTION `calc.label`:  it should look like the following:

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label                       % apalike ignores organization
        'author.key.label                       % for labeling and sorting
      if$
    }
  if$
  ", "                                                  % these three lines are
  *                                                     % for apalike, which
  year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$          % uses all four digits
  *
  'label :=
}
```

Change the line

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$          % uses all four digits
```

to be:

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #64 substring$          % allow many characters
```

Comment: It may not be "good practice," but FWIW it's standard practice in my field.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree, (we're in the same field).  The comment wasn't meant to be a criticism of you.

Comment: You might want to try the `unified.bst` available [here](http://celxj.org/downloads/unified.bst) which allows this sort of citation, and is being adopted by the LSA and some other linguistics journals.

Comment: btw, does somebody know how to escape purify$. i've tried removing it, but then citation year doesn't appear at all. thanks.

Comment: @varun What do you mean by "escape `purify$`"?

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility, although not completely satisfactory, would be to make use of the  `\citeauthor` command and manually enter "(forthcoming)" in the body of text:

```
\citeauthor{key} (forthcoming)
```

Since one rarely cites forthcoming papers (hopefully), this solution might not be that much of a hassle.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer and works best in a pinch.

Comment: This is a little dangerous: when the cited work is published and you update the bibtex, the reference won't update. When I use the solution proposed here (e.g. because I'm dealing with publisher files that I cannot modify), I leave a comment in the bibtex that I have done this, as a reminder to check the references after updating the bibtex.