# Problem with natbib and "To appear" and "In Preparation"

Tags: bibtex, natbib

The following citations produce a text that reads `Meier (To Appear,I)` although the .aux file contains the right information:

```
\relax 
\citation{a,c}
\bibdata{SM}
\bibcite{c}{{1}{In Preparation}{{Meier}}{{}}}
\bibcite{a}{{2}{To Appear}{{Meier}}{{}}}
\bibstyle{natbib.myfullname}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
 @incollection{a, author={Max Meier}, title={My first paper}, year={To Appear}}
 @incollection{c, author={Max Meier}, title={My first paper}, Year={In Preparation}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citet{a,c}


\bibliography{SM}

\bibliographystyle{natbib.myfullname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are expecting?

Comment: What bibliography style is `natbib.myfullname` based on? Without knowing that it's hard to solve this problem. (It's related to how the bib style handles identical authors, but without more details of the actual bib style it's hard to solve.)  Please see if the following question will solve your problem: [Truncation of "year" field in author-year citations using Natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38808)

Comment: OK. Thanks. I think the truncation hint is correct. However, I do not know how to fix this in my bst files. Here is what I am using: http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/natbib.myfullname.bst

Comment: I expect `Meier (To Appear, In Preparation)`.