# Slash in year field in author-year citations using "apalike" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use the natbib package (with the default authoryear option) and the apalike bibliography style for bibliographies.

I would like to cite the following bibtex entry:

```
@article{Lake2010/11,
Author = {Lake, David A.},
Journal = {International Security},
Number = {3},
Pages = {7-52},
Title = {Two Cheers for Bargaining Theory: Assessing Rationalist Explanations of the Iraq War},
Volume = {35},
Year = {2010/11}}
```

When I use `\citep{Lake2010/11}` I get the right output in my bibliography

> Lake, David A. (2010/11), Two Cheers for Bargaining Theory: Assessing Rationalist Explanations of the Iraq War, International Security, 35(3), 7–52.

However, the citation callout in the text is wrong: (Lake, 1011) instead of (Lake, 2010/11)

The problem seems to be the [truncation of the year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/truncation-of-year-field-in-author-year-citations-using-natbib). So I changed the following line

> year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$

to

> year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #14 substring$

Now I get the following output in the text: (Lake, 201011) -- the slash (/) is missing.

Why?

Comment: I know, that I do not need the slash in the key field. But my problem is that there is no slash in (Lake, 2010/11) in the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no truly odd characters in the `year` field, i.e., if the field contains just digits and the occasional `/` ("slash") character, it suffices to change the line

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
```

in the file `apalike.bst` to

```
year field.or.null #-1 #14 substring$
```

Actually, you should make this change to a *copy* of the file `apalike.bst`; don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.

The main change is the elimination of the BibTeX built-in function `purify$`. (As you can probably guess, the function `purify$` purges all non-numeric characters from the field. In the present case, this turns out to be too much of a good thing.)

Save the file `myapalike.bst` (or whatever you may have called the file) either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you select the second method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.

Here's the result of a full MWE. (Note that you should encase "Iraq War" in an extra pair of curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing the letters "I" and "W".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lake201011,
Author = {Lake, David A.},
Journal = {International Security},
Number = {3},
Pages = {7-52},
Title = {Two Cheers for Bargaining Theory: Assessing Rationalist Explanations of the {Iraq War}},
Volume = {35},
Year = {2010/11},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\begin{document}
\citep{Lake201011}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @feder80 - That's correct. It's usually a good thing to purge non-numeric characters from the year field; however, in your case this turns out to be undesirable.