# How to cite "author (year-year)" e.g. a yearbook with just one entry in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib, apa-style

How can I cite an annually published yearbook of a certain author with just one entry in the bibliography while also citing the same author with another publication of the last year cited of the first reference, the yearbook?

Here is the example.

I want to cite:

> Author_1 (1999-2011): Yearbook.

and

> Author_1 (2011): Study.

I am using Jabref.

Currently I paste the years of the yearbook in brackets in the field "year" in Jabref: `{1999-2011}`. In the text I refer to it like this:  `\citeauthor{Reference} (1999-2011)`. In the bibliography then appears:

> Author_1 (1999-2011).

I also need to include the second source, which should appear as

> Author_1 (2011) in the references.

But since I have both references, it ends up to:

> Author_1 (1999-2011a), Author_1 (2011b)

instead of

> Author_1 (1999-2011), Author_1 (2011).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please give us a bit more information? We neither know which bibliography style you are using, nor if you use bibtex or biblatex. If possible, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: I am using \bibliographystyle{apalike} and bibtex. Let me know, if I need to more concise..

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could make a compilable code, which is complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using essentially the same technique as described in the following question:

- [Truncation of "year" field in author-year citations using "apalike" bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38808/2693)

We can make almost the same modification, but with one further change in order to get the `-` in the year range.

So make a copy of `apalike.bst` and name it something else, e.g., `myapalike.bst`.  Then find the function `calc.label` and make the following change:

Change the line

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$   % uses all four digits
```

to be:

```
year field.or.null #-1 #64 substring$          % allow many characters and don't purify
```

Now your example will work as you desire:

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Author1999,
    Editor = {Author, An},
    Publisher = {The Publisher},
    Title = {This is the yearbook},
    Year = {1999-2011}}

@incollection{Author2011,
    Author = {Author, An},
    Editor = {Author, An},
    Booktitle = {This is the yearbook},
    Title = {A chapter of the yearbook},
    Publisher = {The Publisher},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\begin{document}
\cite{Author1999,Author2011}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]