# Biblatex: add "submitted to" or "to appear in" for some publications

Tags: biblatex, citing

Some of my articles are accepted for publication, others are not. In my bibliography I have to state the not yet accepted ones as "Submitted to" and accepted but not published ones as "To appear in". In addition, references for conference papers should include "Paper submitted to". I have added a description of the three different cases illustrating the problem both in connection to a list have made with \fullcite and the bibliography.

[image]

```
%CLASS and GEOMETRY and PDFs
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=2.6cm,right=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=3cm, 
    footskip=.67cm]
    {geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%FONT and language
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.5} % default: 0.4
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.3ex}
\setCJKmainfont{TakaoMincho}

%FLOATS - table and graphics
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2mm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}

% TOC og LOFT mellemrum
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{2mm} 
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{2mm} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{2mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-3}

%GRAPHICS
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%SHORT CUTS
\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\newcommand{\arrl}{\textleftarrow}
\newcommand{\arrr}{\textrightarrow}
\newcommand{\arrlr}{\textleftrightarrow}

\newcommand{\prs}[1]{PrS\sub{#1}}
\newcommand{\pos}[1]{PoS\sub{#1}}
\newcommand{\obs}[1]{ObS\sub{#1}}
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{DS\sub{#1}}

%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sortlocale=danish,
    firstinits=true,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    dashed=false,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=true,]
    {biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
        or
        test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
    }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
    }
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{99}#1}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}[\tempmaxup] %sets name order to last-first 
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @incollection{winslow2018,
        title = {Theorizing {{Lesson Study}}: {{Two}} Related Frameworks and Two {{Danish}} Case-Studies},
        booktitle = {({{To}} Appear) {{Mathematics Lesson Study Around}} the {{World}}: {{Theoretical}} and Methodological Issues},
        series = {Springer book series of ICME},
        publisher = {{Springer}},
        date = {2018},
        author = {Winsløw, Carl and Bahn, Jacob and Rasmussen, Klaus},
        editor = {Quaresma, Marisa and Winsløw, Carl and Clivaz, Stéphane and da Ponte, João and Ní Shúilleabháin, Aoibhinn and Takahashi, Akihiko},

    }
    @article{bahn2017c,
        title = {Evolution of Teachers' Anticipation of Didactical Situations in the Course of Three Lesson Studies},
        journaltitle = {(article submitted for) Annales de didactique et de Sciences Cognitives},
        date = {2017},
        author = {Bahn, Jacob},

    }

    @inproceedings{bahn2017d,
        location = {{Nagoya, Japan}},
        title = {How Infrastructures of Lesson Studies Impact on Teachers' Learning},
        eventtitle = {(Paper Submitted to) {{WALS Conference}} 2017},
        year = {2017/11/24-26},
        author = {Bahn, Jacob},

    }
\end{filecontents}

%TITLE and AUTHOR and FRONTPAGE
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

%FONT 
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\begin{document}
\chapter{List of all papers and abstracts produced }
\noindent \fullcite{bahn2017c}.
\bigskip \noindent \fullcite{bahn2017d}.
\bigskip \noindent \fullcite{winslow2018}.
\section{References} % REFERENCES  ---------------------------------
\sloppy
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us an MWE, please? It is much easier to help you if you show us code that we can actually start from without the need to write a document from scratch. Can you also show how the other answer did not work for you? What in particular can the linked answer not do?

Comment: See the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196182/15925 to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23023/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Those suggestions pose at least two problems (I think): First of all it will affect all entries, and secondly - since It has to be done in the .bib-file - I would not be able to automatic update from Zotero when I edit or add entries.

Comment: How would you like to tell `biblatex` which entries are submitted to and which are to appear in if not via the `.bib` file? Can you show us what output you expect exactly?

Comment: Well, I don't know but I guess I was hoping that there is some way to locally tell tex to differ. I will add en example to the OP.

Comment: The specific answer I pointed to, adding a pubstate field, only affects the given individual entry.  Can you create custom fields in Zotero?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I cannot create custom fields, but moewe pointed me to this trick which works well: https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/wiki/Customized-Exports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The straightforward solution is an extension of lockstep's answer to [Localize terms in bibtex/biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25088/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  booktitle = {Foo},
  editor = {Emma Ditor},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pubstate = {toappear},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{toappear}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  toappear = {to appear},
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \iffieldundef{pubstate}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \clearfield{pubstate}}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}

\begin{document}
\cite{A01,westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

A more involved solution that handles different prepositions would be

```
\NewBibliographyString{toappearin}
\NewBibliographyString{submittedto}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  toappearin  = {to appear in},
  submittedto = {submitted to},
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{pubstate}}
              and (test {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{toappearin}}
                   or test{\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{submittedto}})}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{pubstate}\intitlepunct}%
     \clearfield{pubstate}}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

**In addition**: This solution works perfect in combination with the export trick revealed here: https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/wiki/Customized-Exports

Comment: Thanks. It works for individual paper, but I can't make it work for contributions to a book.

Comment: @jbahn Show an MWE. This will definitely work for `@incollection` and `@inbook` as well as `@article`. For `@book`s it will not work as it is not clear where to place the 'to appear in'.

Comment: Would it be possible to make something like: if 'year' = 'to appear' set 'in-style' to 'To appear in'?

Comment: I got it as far as to have it write 'toappearin' instead of 'In:'. That's progress! Rather than adding a pubstate field in the .bib-file, I used the note field in Zotero. It seems to work, but I can't make it go the rest of the way, to print 'To appear in:' instead of 'toappearin:'.

Comment: EDIT: It also seems to only allow EITHER 'toappearin' OR 'submittedto' to have effect.

Comment: @jbahn I'll be away for a few days, so I won't have time to look at this. sorry. I don't quite understand what you are doing at the moment. Ideally you would use the `pubstate` field and not `note` or `year` (since that is the semantically correct field). If Zotero does not allow you to export to that field you might want to look at https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex, I haven't used it personally, but I believe it gives you more control over the fields Zotero writes (could be wrong there).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll figure something out. Happy New Year!

Comment: The combination of your code and the trick you linked to works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @moewe BBT gives full control over the fields Zotero writes.